# Same batchId, subscriberId and different jobId in the same day for a particual trigger

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, history-tracking

Basically we have a nightly dump of everything from E.T. but the JOBID is missing. So far for a particular trigger i was able to fetch 100% just by batch and subscriber, and i noticed that the jobid changes very seldomly anyway.

So my question is "**is it possible for the same trigger to have the same batch, subscriber but different job in the same day?**" I tried to browse the documentation for it but couldn't find anything relevant....

Please let me know it this is the case or if I missed something....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible.  The JobID for a given Triggered Send will only change when the definition is republished so under normal circumstances it would be pretty rare.

Comment: sorry, could you tell me when the definition is republished for a trigger definition? Does that mean that is when it is changed?

Comment: When a triggered definition is running, no changes can be made to it until it is paused.  Once paused, changes can be made but those changes will not be live until the Publish button is used.   It is possible to pause, update, and restart a triggered definition without publishing it which would mean the changes wouldn't be live. Updating it does not force a publish, the option in the UI needs to be selected or the RefreshContent property in the API needs to be set to true when doing an update on the TriggeredSendDefinition object.

Comment: Make sure @user5593 that you mark this answered by checking the check mark.